# flex FDT: how can supress warnings for specific lines?

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I use FDT for my flex programming and there are some warnings that I want to suppress.

for example:

```
Private function is never used. Found 'list_itemRendererFunc' at line foo column bar.
```

I actually paste this function name as a string to a datagroup's itemRendererFunction property. how do I mark this line that will not show the warning ?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're running into a warning (such as you say in the subject) or an error (Such as you say in the body).  But, you can supremos warnings using the 'show-actionscript-warnings' argument and setting it to false.

Look at all compiler arguments here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html

Comment: the 'errors' was a typo. 'X is never used' is obviously not an error. the show-actionscript-warnings argument is for the entire project or file. i want to supress warnings for a specific line of code.

Comment: @ufk You can't suppress warnings for a single line of code so far as I know [aside from commenting out that line]

Comment: every other language that i know supports it though.

Comment: @ufk I can't say I've used one where I've looked for this option; but I've done little work with "true" compiled languages.

Comment: ok so i'll accept this answer. it's not possible to suppress warnings on specific lines, the only suppress warnings available is written in this answer.